# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error RapidClipse

Tags: server, internals, rapidclipse

I have a new Laptop and I want to work again on my RapidClipse project. So i installed RapidClipse, opened my project and got on the Designer an Internal Server Error. I googled it and can't find any solutions. Here is the Error Code:

```
Type Exception Report

Message com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Push is not available. See previous log messages for more information.

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Push is not available. See previous log messages for more information.
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:382)
    com.xdev.communication.XdevServlet.service(XdevServlet.java:207)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.AddDefaultCharsetFilter.doFilter(AddDefaultCharsetFilter.java:88)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
Root Cause

com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Push is not available. See previous log messages for more information.
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1487)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1447)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
    com.xdev.communication.XdevServlet.service(XdevServlet.java:207)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.AddDefaultCharsetFilter.doFilter(AddDefaultCharsetFilter.java:88)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Push is not available. See previous log messages for more information.
    com.vaadin.ui.PushConfigurationImpl.setPushMode(PushConfiguration.java:207)
    com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:210)
    com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1435)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
    com.xdev.communication.XdevServlet.service(XdevServlet.java:207)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.AddDefaultCharsetFilter.doFilter(AddDefaultCharsetFilter.java:88)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFMkR.png)

Answer (score 0):

There can be many issue. First there is nothing to do with new old laptop. Second configuration of your project might be outdated, or if you have installed any external plug in it can cause issues as well.

For troubleshoot:
1. Uninstall rapidclipse.
2. Delete .m2 and .p2 folders from user home directory depending on OS.
3. Move your project folder somewhere else delete the workspace.
4. Re-install rapidclipse.
5. Create new workspace.
6. Copy your project into new workspace.
7. Import it into your rapidclipse.